# Using Remote notification with deployment target 8.1 and XCODE 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

I want to use remote notification with deployment target 8.1 and xcode 6.1
i am using following code

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

But it shows me `deprecated` methods in else part....so now how can i get rid of it...
and the other code what i tried is:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you have also as deployment target ios7 or lower? than make a clean build and build again

Answer (score 2):

You could ignore deprecate warning like this:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_8_0
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

    }
#else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
#endif
```

See  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554449/deprecated-warnings-in-xcode-and-how-to-handle-deprecation):

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following code might serve your need

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: No buddy ..same thing i use'd ..but not works..thanks

Comment: are you using deployment target 8.1 and xcode 6.1??

Comment: i'll try everything with this link...   http://corinnekrych.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-support-push-notification-for.html

Comment: @Bhavin please copy and paste my code and then run.

Comment: @SumitGarg i post an image ...checked it out

Comment: This is the best approach for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The method `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` is depricated from iOS 8.0. Since you are compiling using iOS 8.1 SDK you will get the warning. It is an expected behavior and your application will work properly as your application will use `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` if and only if your iOS version is less than 8.0 where the method `registerUserNotificationSettings:` is defined.

If you need to avoid any depreciation warning you can use `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` flag to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I can understand your problem you have used deployment target 8.1.
just change deployment target less than or equal to 7, otherwise remove else part because no need to define this in 8.1 target

Comment: i think, if deployment target is 8.1 then it supports only that iphone which uses 8.1 os...right??

Comment: @Bhavin yes ios 8.1 and above